# Writing Test in ink! smart contract

Tags: ink, unit-tests, e2e

I have two contract `nft_contract` and `staking_contract`. I want to write test for `staking_contract` but while staking I need to mint nft and approve, then only I can use it to stake. How can this be done? Someone please give some idea?

This is [github_code](https://github.com/Build3rs-Labs/foxies/tree/main/contracts)

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you need to write e2e tests. I did something similar some time ago. Check [this](https://github.com/swankyhub/rmrk-lazy-mint/blob/507552ced20d948b6acb34eb75855f84f30357fa/rmrk_proxy/proxy.rs#L365) for inspiration